# How to unit test a KinesisRecord-based DoFn?

Tags: java, apache-beam, amazon-kinesis-analytics

I’m getting started on a Beam project that reads from AWS Kinesis, so I have a simple DoFn that accepts a KinesisRecord and logs the contents. I want to write a unit test to run this DoFn and prove that it works. Unit testing with a KinesisRecord has proven to be challenging, though.

I get this error when I try to just use `Create.of(testKinesisRecord)`:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to infer a coder and no Coder was specified. Please set a coder by invoking Create.withCoder() explicitly  or a schema by invoking Create.withSchema().
```

I have tried providing the KinesisRecordCoder explicitly using "withCoder" as the error suggests, but it’s a private class. Perhaps there's another way to unit test a DoFn?

Test code:

```
public class MyProjectTests {
    @Rule
    public TestPipeline p = TestPipeline.create();

    @Test
    public void testPoC() {
        var testKinesisRecord = new KinesisRecord(
                ByteBuffer.wrap("SomeData".getBytes()),
                "seq01",
                12,
                "pKey",
                Instant.now().minus(Duration.standardHours(4)),
                Instant.now(),
                "MyStream",
                "shard-001"
        );


        PCollection<Void> output =
                p.apply(Create.of(testKinesisRecord))
                        .apply(ParDo.of(new MyProject.PrintRecordFn()));

        var result = p.run();
        result.waitUntilFinish();
        result.metrics().allMetrics().getCounters().forEach(longMetricResult -> {
            Assertions.assertEquals(1, longMetricResult.getCommitted().intValue());
        });
    }
}
```

DoFn code:

```
  static class PrintRecordFn extends DoFn<KinesisRecord, Void> {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PrintRecordFn.class);
    private final Counter items = Metrics.counter(PrintRecordFn.class, "itemsProcessed");

    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(@Element KinesisRecord element) {
      items.inc();

      LOG.info("Stream: `{}` Shard: `{}` Arrived at `{}`\nData: {}",
              element.getStreamName(),
              element.getShardId(),
              element.getApproximateArrivalTimestamp(),
              element.getDataAsBytes());
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`KinesisRecordCoder` is supposed to be used for internal purposes, so it is made package private. In the same time, you can provide custom `AWSClientsProvider` and use it to generate test data. As an example, please, take a look on [KinesisMockReadTest](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/kinesis/src/test/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/kinesis/KinesisMockReadTest.java) and custom [Provider](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/808cb35018cd228a59b152234b655948da2455fa/sdks/java/io/kinesis/src/test/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/kinesis/AmazonKinesisMock.java#L159)